# How to find whether a sentence contain a noun using spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, dependency-parsing

Currently doing a project in NLP. I need to find out whether a sentence have a noun in it. How can I achieve this using spacy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'hello india how are you?')
print(len([np.text for np in doc.noun_chunks])>0)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'hello india how are you?')
print(len([token.pos_ for token in doc if token.pos_=="NOUN"])>0)
```

Comment: The first solution gives `True` but the second solution gives `False`.  
The following code fixes it. "India" gets evaluated as a proper noun, so the boolean logic needs to include either.  
`print(len([token.pos_ for token in doc if token.pos_=="NOUN" or "PROPN"])>0)`